# variables of type char* in c++

Tags: c++, string, char

In a C++ code, I need to get a string from the user and get it into a variable of type char*, something like this:

```
string word1;
char * word2;
int something;

cin>>word1;

for (int i=0;i<something; i++)
word2[i]=word1[i];
```

but I cant seem to get it right, any help?

Comment: `I need to get a string from the user and get it into a variable of type char*` No you don't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that you have not allocated any memory for `word2` yet when you were trying to do:

```
word2[i] = word1[i];
```

in the loop.

It is not clear what you are trying to do. However, given `word1`, you can convert it to `const char *` with the `c_str()` member function from `std::string` library.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the code which would work in your case:

```
// Define the string
string word1;

// Read a line until '\n' to the word1
std::getline(cin, word1);

// Define a char array and allocate memory it
char * word2 = new char[word1.size() + 1];

// Null-terminate the array (in case if you need to print it)
word2[word1.size()] = 0;

// Place the letters to the new array
memcpy(word2, word1.c_str(), word1.size());
```

Source: [How do i convert string to char array? - C++ Forum](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/4422/)

Or, if you wold rather prefer to do it in your character-by-character way:

```
// Define the string
string word1;

// Read a line until '\n' to the word1
std::getline(cin, word1);

// Define a char array and allocate memory it
char * word2  = new char[word1.size() + 1];

// Get the word word1 length
int wordLength = word1.size();

// Convert one string to another symbol-by-symbol
for (int i = 0; i < wordLength; i ++)
    word2[i] = word1.c_str()[i];

// Null-terminate the array (in case if you need to print it)
word2[wordLength] = 0;
```

Note: do not forget to `#include <string.h>` for the `memcpy()`, which is used to preserve the original string from changes.

UPD: the code is updated with reading user input into the string.

Comment: Okay but this is bad form _and_ you have a memory leak.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, explain it please then :)

Comment: I'd stick with a `std::vector<char>` or `std::unique_ptr<char[]>` (if the vector doesn't work out for some reason) so the memory is managed for you.

Comment: @Danek: Explain what?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, where does the memory leak occur, and what is bad in the approach.

Comment: @Danek: Where does the memory leak occur? You `new[]` and do not `delete[]`. As for why this approach is bad, it's because manual memory management went the way of the dinosaur about 15 years ago; the OP simply _shouldn't_ store `char*`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, talking about `new[]` without `delete[]`, I would say that I am just leaving the newly made string for the OP to use, since it is not the whole program but a chunk of code. If I delete it now, then it would not be usable later, so it's not a point at all.
Talking about "badness", for modern C++ it is not bad, bud obsolete. Storing `*char` is usable though, when you do, for instance, CUDA programming with plain C. So, it is not bad, but rather used in a wrong place. Moreover, OP requested a conversion to `char[]`, so I answered his question.